# Update table with data on same table by group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like the following:

[image]

You will realize that the table is divided into two groups by **descrip**. The groups are **'one'** and **'two'**. I want to update 
I wish to update the ids for 2016 to reflect the ids id for 2013 for each group. So, after the update, the descrip **'one'** should have 1 for id and the descrip **'two'** should have 2 for id.
So the table should look like:

[image]

The solution cannot be something like:

```
update tab set id =1 where descrip ='one'
update tab set id =2 where descrip ='two'
```

because the actual table is much longer than the one shown.

This is what I have so far:

```
UPDATE t 
SET t.id = (SELECT TOP 1 t2.id
                 FROM dbo.tab t2
                 WHERE t2.yr = 2013)
FROM dbo.tab t
WHERE t.yr = 2016
```

But, of course, it only updates one descrip properly

Comment: How many rows are we talking?

Comment: @JohnHC About 1000

Comment: I assume that you mean 1000 different descriptions, yes? 1000 rows is trivial on a database, but hard coding 1000 different sets of data is not something to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE dbo.tab
SET id = CASE WHEN desc='one' THEN 1
              WHEN desc='two' THEN 2
        END;
```

If you get an ACTIVE TRANSACTION LOG full error, you will have to chunk it. Some suggestions:

```
UPDATE dbo.tab
SET id = CASE WHEN desc='one' THEN 1
              WHEN desc='two' THEN 2
        END
WHERE
    id <> CASE WHEN desc='one' THEN 1
              WHEN desc='two' THEN 2
        END
    AND yr = 2013;

UPDATE dbo.tab
SET id = CASE WHEN desc='one' THEN 1
              WHEN desc='two' THEN 2
        END
WHERE
    id <> CASE WHEN desc='one' THEN 1
              WHEN desc='two' THEN 2
        END
    AND yr = 2016;
```

Comment: @KieraSmith You will need to chunk. But by itself, 1000 rows should NOT be a problem for ANY database.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DENSE_RANK` window function

```
select Yr,DENSE_RANK()Over(Partition by year Order by Id) as Id,descrip
From yourtable
```

Comment: @vkp - No I guess., as per sample data

Answer (score 0):

This should handle non-sequential IDs, multiple descrip, etc.

```
With cte as (
    SELECT 
        min(tab.id) as id, 
        tab.descrip
    FROM tab
    WHERE tab.yr = 2013
    GROUP BY descrip
    )
UPDATE t 
SET t.id = cte.id
FROM dbo.tab t
INNER JOIN cte
    ON t.descrip = cte.descrip
WHERE t.yr = 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self join

```
update t1
  set id=t2.id
from tab t1 inner join tab t2
on t1.descrip=t2.descrip
and t1.yr=2016 and t2.yr=2013
```

the other alternative building on your code is to make it a proper correlated sub-query:

```
UPDATE t 
SET t.id = (SELECT TOP 1 t2.id
                 FROM dbo.tab t2
                 WHERE t2.yr = 2013 and t2.descrip=t.descrip)
FROM dbo.tab t
WHERE t.yr = 2016
```